# Regex: Getting FPS from FFMPEG log

Tags: php, regex, ffmpeg, preg-match

I try and try again with Regex, I just don't *get it*. I'm trying to traverse a log file for FFMPEG and get the FPS.

Basically, on a variable line (seems to be around 16/17) of the log file this line appears:-

```
Stream #0.1[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p, 640x480 [PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 104857 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 25 tbc
```

I'd like to traverse line by line, which I think I can do exploding by /n and then for loop through, but I'd prefer to just get the line that line, and then get the FPS value.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Comment: Does the line always start with `Stream `? In that case `/^Stream .+?, (\d+) fps(,|$)/` is worth a shot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
if (preg_match('/^Stream #0.*?(\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*fps\b).*/m', $subject, $regs)) {
    $full_line = $regs[0];
    $result = $regs[1];
} else {
    // no match...
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
^     # start of line (/m modifier makes sure that this works)
Stream #0  # match Stream #0 literally
.*?   # match any number of characters, as few as possible
(     # then capture the following
 \b   # starting at a "word" boundary
 \d+  # one or more digits
 (?:  # try to match the following:
  \.  # a dot
  \d+ # followed by one or more digits
 )?   # but make that optional
 \s*  # optional whitespace
 fps  # literal fps
 \b   # end at a word boundary
)     # end of capturing group
.*    # match the rest of the line
```

Comment: +1 Nice! I'd replace `\s+` with `\s*` though (this is strictly subjective as I have no idea whether "zero-or-more" is more or less likely than "one-or-more").

Comment: @jensgram: Thanks, I think it's better that way. I also added an optional group for dealing with NTSC (29.97 fps) and other odd frame rates.

Comment: This seems to work great, thanks! I will just ask one other question with it... can it be strictly on the line that starts with Stream #0? As it is currently (though I can just kill it after it's found the first instanst) returning all FPS statements in the log (for which there are many)?

Comment: Nice one Tim. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just a word of warning... Stream has a space at the start of the line (    ) <- that much... so I had to add that to get it to work. :)

Comment: Just want to quickly say thanks for the explanation as well. Bookmarked for future preg_match tasks.. very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I've just encountered it erroring when getting an fps of 23.98 fps it found 98. Sorry to ask, but how is that negated?

Comment: OH, you're right. This is an error in my regex. I'll correct this right away.